# Logic Pro - How to delete an empty MIDI section?

Tags: midi, editing, logic-pro

Say I have a 16 bar MIDI region full of MIDI events.

Now I delete the last eight bars of events -- and am left with a long section of silence which I'd like to get rid of. After deleting this section, the final duration of my MIDI region should be 8 bars.

I have not found how to do this on Logic documentation.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a pretty good question already, but a screenshot showing exactly what the section you want to delete looks like in Logic would make it even better!

Comment: Is there any way to ask logic to automatically select empty midi regions then delete them? through a menu option perhaps? Context: I program drums using battery 4 on a single midi track, then use the " separate by midi note " function to get them on different tracks in the arrange for easy visibilty and re-arrangement. Only thing is that once separated, I have to go through manually to cut out the bits of empty region in the hi hat track where there is no hi hat etc. pretty laborious. Must be a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either trim the end of the region by dragging it from the right bottom corner of the region.

Or you can use the scissors tool (`Esc`, then `5`), split the region 8 bars in and delete the half that is silent (then double click `Esc` to go back to the pointer tool).

Alternatively, in the piano roll, you can set the end marker for the region - it is shown as a rectangle on the timeline, and you can drag it.

Comment: thanks - another option i found was to put the playhead where the MIDI events end and go Edit > Trim > Crop outside locators (^C)